# Selenium WebDriver fails test when called from Atlassian Bamboo build

Tags: java, linux, selenium, bamboo

I have an app that needs to be build on linux. it has a web interface(hence, the Selenium). In order to test functionality I install the app on a linux VM and have another windows VM running windows XP. My bamboo instantiates these two machines, installs the app on linux and runs a selenium test from the windows machine to test some things out. 

The problem is that my test, which is based on IE driver, it always fails when searching for a specific element(a checkbox) be it by xpath or id, it doesn't matter. It fails when the build is ran from Bamboo only!
If I run the test from my workspace it works crystal clear on the windows machine and it's OK. But when bamboo calls it, it always fails searching for that one element; element that it normally finds.

I can't understand why it would work if I run it, but it wouldn't work if I run it from Bamboo build.

here is the process: upload a file->click create->goes to another page->searches for the checkbox and gives the timeout exception

P.S. The test itself uploads a file. When i run the test from my workspace this happens normally, but when I run it from Bamboo it freezes a little there before it continues, but eventually resumes. Don't know if it is relevant

P.S.2 i'm sorry for not being too specific, this is a work related problem and I can't say much.

***UPDATE***
It seems that when the file is uploaded, the IE kinda freezes for some seconds(20-30 or so). Strange thing is that it freezes only when ran from bamboo, when I run it, it works great, it sends the keys(filepath/file) to the file element immediately. On the bamboo on the other hand, when it freezes it seems the selenium test doesn't wait for the operation to finish and moves on. This is the reason i think it can't find the element. It's not a normal system freeze("not responding"), it just waits for a while then resumes. If the selenium moves onward, this might explain why it can't find my webelement, since is not on that page. I will come back to this

Comment: Have you solved it yet?
If not, make sure that your PC and the Windows PC used by Bamboo use the same version of Selenium. (btw, is it WebDriver or something else?) There can also be a poor connection between the Win and Linux machines which could cause timeout exceptions. You may try to increase timeouts and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, both of them use the same selenium driver. And yes, it is selenium WebDriver. The PC and bamboo machine are in the same network. I'm trying a workaround but someone messed up the build and i cant test it yet. I will let you know about my progress

Comment: have you resolved you problem? could you share how you resolved your problem as i am also running from the same problem

Comment: we moved to jenkins..